# Is there a way to get the URL fom a .URL file using C#? I've thought of going into the properties to get it, but I'm open to any suggestions

Tags: c#

I've been tasked with writing a program that can find any hyperlinks in .docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .lnk and .url files. I have all of them figured out except for the .url part. I've thought about the possibility of getting it from the files properties, but I'm also not sure if his is possible.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Here's a successful attempt at getting links from a word document.

```
string pathtofolder = "C:\\Users\\Icmolreulf\\source\\repos\\FileSearch\\FileSearch\\testing\\";
string[] docx = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathtofolder, "*.docx", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int i = 0; i < docx.Length; i++)
            {
                WordprocessingDocument word = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docx[i], true);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                IEnumerable<HyperlinkRelationship> link = from x in word.MainDocumentPart.HyperlinkRelationships where (x.RelationshipType == "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink") select x;
                
            if (!link.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No links found in " + docx[i] + ".");
            }
            else
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Links found in " + docx[i] + ":");
                 sw.WriteLine("Links found in " + docx[i] + ":");
                 foreach (HyperlinkRelationship l in link)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(l.Uri.ToString());
                    sw.WriteLine(l.Uri.ToString());
                    }
                sw.WriteLine("\n");
            }
         }
```

Comment: Show us your successful approaches.

Comment: Or one of them, anyway.  Without some context, it's difficult to offer any advice.

Comment: [the .url-format](https://fileinfo.com/extension/url) seems straightforward enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.url` files are text based.

So one approach is to read it line by line till you find:

> `URL=[URL Address]`